# How can I decompose the $\max$ of a product of functions?

Tags: maxima-minima

In this [video](https://youtu.be/RwwfUICZLsA?t=234), the author states that if $f(x) \geq 0$ for every $x$ and $g(x,y) \geq 0$ for every $x$ and $y$, then
$$
\max_{x,y} f(x)g(x,y) = \max_x \left[f(x) \cdot \max_y g(x,y)\right]
$$
I tried to prove this equality using $\log$'s as follows.
\begin{align}
\log\left(\max_{x,y} f(x)g(x,y)\right) &= \max_{x,y} \log f(x) + \log g(x,y) \\
&= \max_{x} \log f(x) + \max_{x,y} \log g(x,y) \tag{1} \\
&= \max_x \left[\log f(x) + \max_y \log g(x,y)\right] \tag{2}
\end{align}
I would then compute the $\exp$ of both sides of this equation to get the result. However, I think going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ is incorrect, but not exactly sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, the following general rule is being used:
$$\sup_{x, y} h(x, y) = \sup_x \sup_y h(x, y),$$
This is not difficult to see. Note that
$$\sup_x \sup_y h(x, y) \ge \sup_y h(x_0, y) \ge h(x_0, y_0)$$
for all $x_0, y_0$, so
$$\sup_{x, y} h(x, y) \le \sup_x \sup_y h(x, y).$$
On the other hand, $\sup_{x, y} h(x, y) \ge h(x_0, y_0)$ for any particular $x_0, y_0$, so if we take the supremum of both sides with respect to $y_0$ (bearing in mind that the left hand side is a constant with respect to $y_0$, we obtain
$$\sup_{x, y} h(x, y) \ge \sup_{y_0} h(x_0, y_0) = \sup_y h(x_0, y),$$
for all $x_0$. Taking now the supremum of both sides with respect to $x_0$,
$$\sup_{x, y} h(x, y) \ge \sup_{x_0} \sup_y h(x_0, y) = \sup_x \sup_y h(x, y),$$
completing the proof.

---

If the suprema are achieved on the right hand side, then all the suprema (including on the left hand side) are maxima instead. This means we can conclude:
$$\max_{x, y} f(x)g(x, y) = \max_x \max_y f(x)g(x, y).$$
The only ingredient missing is that, if $\alpha \ge 0$, then $\sup_x \alpha h(x) = \alpha \sup_x h(x)$. This is essentially true by the fact that multiplication by $\alpha > 0$ preserves strict inequality, and a special case argument for $\alpha = 0$. Since $f(x) \ge 0$ is a constant with respect to $y$, we get
$$\max_y f(x) g(x, y) = f(x) \max_y g(x, y).$$
Taking the maximum over $x$ of both sides completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, here is another version of @TheoBendit's proof that has a bit more commentary (the second part of @TheoBendit's answer that discusses $\max_{x, y} f(x)g(x, y)$ is not discussed here) and shows that $$\min_{x,y} h(x,y) = \min_{x} \left[ \min_{y} h(x,y) \right]$$ To prove this, we want to show that $$\min_{x,y} h(x,y) \geq \min_{x} \left[ \min_{y} h(x,y) \right]$$ and $$\min_{x,y} h(x,y) \leq \min_{x} \left[ \min_{y} h(x,y) \right]$$ First, we show that $$\min_{x,y} h(x,y) \geq \min_{x} \left[ \min_{y} h(x,y) \right]$$ Note that
\begin{align}
\min_{x} \left[ \min_{y} h(x,y) \right] &\leq \min_y h(x_0,y) \\
&\leq h(x_0,y_0)
\end{align}
for every pair $(x_0,y_0)$, including the pair $(\bar x, \bar y)$ that minimizes $h(x,y)$. That is, if $h(\bar x,\bar y) = \min_{x,y} h(x,y)$, then we can write,
\begin{align}
\min_{x} \left[ \min_{y} h(x,y) \right] &\leq h(\bar x,\bar y) \\
&= \min_{x,y} h(x,y)
\end{align}
and so we have shown that $$\min_{x,y} h(x,y) \geq \min_{x} \left[ \min_{y} h(x,y) \right]$$ Next, we show that $$\min_{x,y} h(x,y) \leq \min_{x} \left[ \min_{y} h(x,y) \right]$$ Note that $$\min_{x,y} h(x,y) \leq h(x_0,y_0)$$ for every pair $(x_0,y_0)$. Then, we can apply $\min_{y_0}[\cdot]$ followed by $\min_{x_0}[\cdot]$ to both sides of this inequality to get
\begin{align}
\min_{x,y} h(x,y) &\leq h(x_0,y_0) \\
\min_{x_0} \left[ \min_{y_0} \left[ \min_{x,y} h(x,y) \right] \right] &\leq \min_{x_0} \left[ \min_{y_0} h(x_0,y_0) \right] 
\end{align}
Because $\min_{x,y} h(x,y)$ on the left-hand side of this inequality is a constant, then this inequality becomes
\begin{align}
\min_{x,y} h(x,y) &\leq \min_{x_0} \left[ \min_{y_0} h(x_0,y_0) \right]
\end{align}
By changing the variables $x_0$ to $x$ and $y_0$ to $y$ on the right-hand side of this inequality, it becomes $$\min_{x,y} h(x,y) \leq \min_{x} \left[ \min_{y} h(x,y) \right]$$ which completes the proof.